# Testing Struct Data

Tags: solidity, testing, struct, mocha

I have a struct and getter function that should return the id to zero when I delete it from my function but I dont know on how to return from my testing script

Here is my struct, mapping & functions that i wanted to test
From SC

```
struct Campaign {
        address owner;
        string title;
        string description;
        uint256 target;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountCollected;
        string image;
        address[] donators;
        uint256[] donations;
        bool claimed;
    }
// a getter mapping
 mapping(uint256 => Campaign) public campaigns;

// delete the campaign id using this function
function cancelCampaign(uint256 _id, address _owner) external {
        Campaign memory campaign = campaigns[_id];
        if (_owner != msg.sender) revert CrowdFund__NotOwner();
        if (campaign.deadline > block.timestamp) revert CrowdFund__Started();

        delete campaigns[_id];

        emit CancelCampaign(_id);
    }

// another getter function based on the total campaign created from a specific user
function getCampaigns() public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        Campaign[] memory allCampaigns = new Campaign[](numberOfCampaigns);

        for (uint i = 0; i < numberOfCampaigns; i++) {
            Campaign storage item = campaigns[i];

            allCampaigns[i] = item;
        }
        return allCampaigns;
    }
```

So on my test script, i wanted to test the cancelCampaign function and delete the id. I tested it on Remix but it returns to a struct object so I'm not sure on how to put it on my test.

Test script

```
describe("Cancel Campaign", () => {
    describe("Success", () => {
      let deadline: any, remove: any, result: any;
      const hundredDays = 100 * 24 * 60 * 60;
      const increasetime = async () => {
        await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [hundredDays]);
        await network.provider.send("evm_mine");
      };
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await increasetime();
        deadline = await time.latest();
        await cf
          .connect(user1)
          .createCampaign(
            user1.address,
            "Test Title",
            "Test Description",
            token(1),
            deadline,
            "Image1.jpeg"
          );
        await cf.connect(user1).cancelCampaign(1, user1.address);
      });

      it("should delete the campaign id", async () => {
        expect(await cf.connect(user1).getCampaigns()).to.equal(0);
      });
    });
  });
```

This is what I get when I tested it in Remix:

```
{
    "0": "address: owner 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "1": "string: title ",
    "2": "string: description ",
    "3": "uint256: target 0",
    "4": "uint256: deadline 0",
    "5": "uint256: amountCollected 0",
    "6": "string: image "
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you asset equal to the following struct:

```
{
    "0": "address: owner 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "1": "string: title ",
    "2": "string: description ",
    "3": "uint256: target 0",
    "4": "uint256: deadline 0",
    "5": "uint256: amountCollected 0",
    "6": "string: image "
}
```

If thats what you are looking for anyway?

Comment: Tried to put this on my test but still getting the same result

Comment: Can you check each struct position individually? Maybe make a loop function to determine the size of the mapping and that it is 0 or 1. I do wish there was more documentation for testing things like this, or if there was print functionality. In a similar situation I have amended my smart contract with check functions to be able to test certain things like this.